# SDK and callback after sign

Tags: docusignapi

We are using Docusign SDK for python, we are sending the envelope and after sign the callback are passing by RecipientViewRequest in returnUrl are be calling, and all are working ok, but we need to receive both emails (review & sign and concluded) and we are getting just the concluded email.

After some research we found that it's because we are using the clientUserId, after remove this key, both emails are sent, but the callback in returnUrl is not called anymore.

Is there a way to receive both emails and still have the callback in returnUrl?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want the sender to receive the signer_signed email for embedded signers.

Check the eSignature settings tool:

1. Open settings from the DocuSign web application
2. Click `Signing Settings` in the left column
3. Scroll down the page to the **Envelope Delivery** section at the bottom of the page.
4. Check that **Suppress emails to embedded signers** is NOT checked
5. You may also want to check the **Send completion emails to embedded signers** option

[image]

#### Alternate notification

If the above doesn't work...

When you set a signer to be embedded (by setting clientUserId) and use the RecipientViewRequest to show an embedded signing ceremony, the assumption is that your application can manage any necessary notifications.

With embedded signing, after the signer completes the signing ceremony, your application is called and the URL includes the `event` query parameter.

If the `event` is `complete` then the signer has signed.

In that case, your application can notify the sender by sending its own email or notification.